# How to use "this" as a parameter of a function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this javascript code:

```
function changeIn(ele,clr){
  var elem = document.getElementById(ele);
  elem.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
  elem.style.background=clr;
}
function changeOut(ele){
 var elem=document.getElementById(ele);
 elem.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
 elem.style.background="#9DCEFF";
}
```

Then I call the function on HTML,

```
<div id="boxOne" onmouseover="changeIn(this,'#F0F')"  onmouseout="changeOut(this)">Some content</div>
```

But don't work. How can I apply the function to boxOne using *this* as parameter? Thanks.

Comment: Why not to use `event.target` in event handler instead of passing `this`...

Comment: Your functions expect a string, but you're passing a dom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find out the element again inside the method. Just use your parameter

```
function changeIn(ele,clr){
  ele.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
  ele.style.background=clr;
}
```

The line which causing an issue is

```
var elem = document.getElementById(ele);
```

here `ele` is an DOM element not the element's Id. So the resultant variable of above expression i.e. `elem` becomes `undefined`. So you can directly use the DOM element inside you function.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8pe9a2qo/)

Answer (score 2):

`this` will pass the DOM Object itself, not its ID. You don't need the `getElementById()` request because the `ele` parameter already references the DOM element. Simply update your two functions as follows:

```
function changeIn( ele, clr )
{
    ele.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
    ele.style.background=clr;
}

function changeOut( ele )
{
   ele.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
   ele.style.background="#9DCEFF";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one:

```
function changeIn(ele,clr){

    ele.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
    ele.style.background=clr;
}

function changeOut(ele){
    ele.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
    ele.style.background="#9DCEFF";
}
```

In your div `onmouseover="changeIn(this,'#F0F')"` `this` == `ele` of your `changeIn(ele,clr)` function.

So **you don't need to find element**

```
var elem = document.getElementById(ele);
```

since `this` is **already DOM element**. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The `this` object is already the DOM element you seek. Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lty70h7a/

### HTML

```
<div id="boxOne" onmouseover="changeIn(this,'#F0F')"  onmouseout="changeOut(this)">Some content</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
window.changeIn = function(elem,clr){
    elem.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
    elem.style.backgroundColor=clr;
};
window.changeOut = function(elem){
    elem.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
    elem.style.backgroundColor="#9DCEFF";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.target`.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74y7exp3/

```
function changeIn(clr){
  var elem = event.target;
  elem.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
  elem.style.background=clr;
}
function changeOut(ele){
  var elem=event.target;
  elem.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
  elem.style.background="#9DCEFF";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try This:-

```js
function changeIn(ele,clr){
  var elem = document.getElementById(ele.id);
  elem.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
  elem.style.background=clr;
}
function changeOut(ele){
 var elem=document.getElementById(ele.id);
 elem.style.transition = "background  1.0s linear 0s";
 elem.style.background="#9DCEFF";
}
```

```html
<div id="boxOne" onmouseover="changeIn(this,'#F0F')"  onmouseout="changeOut(this)">Some content</div>
```